# Postgres - count of GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, count

I am trying to determine the total number of contributors in an image database who have contributed at least five images. The following query will give me counts of images by contributor, but that's only part of the puzzle. I'm sure this is simple to someone who has more knowledge than me :)

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS i_count, contributor_id
FROM images
GROUP BY contributor_id
ORDER BY i_count DESC
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To count how many contributors have contributed 5 images or more:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number_of_contributors
FROM
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM images 
    GROUP BY contributor_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
  ) AS t ;
```

It could be written without the derived table but it's obfuscated:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS number_of_contributors
FROM images 
GROUP BY contributor_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5 
LIMIT 1 ;
```

(there is a slight difference between the two queries. If there are no contributors with 5+ images, the first query will return one row with `0`. The second query will return no rows.)

Comment: So what does the `1` represent in `SELECT 1` in the derived table?

Comment: Also - please forgive the noob questions - what is the purpose of `AS t`?

Comment: @andrewniesen: `1`is just an integer value, the most basic, cheap thing to put there, because in the next query level only the number of rows matters. [`AS t` is a table alias](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES). Basic SQL questions are better directed to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: What Erwin said above. I could be `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT contributer_id` instead of `SELECT 1`. We just need something there so we have a row for each contributor that then the external query can count them (the rows of `t`, the rows that the internal query produces).